# How can I make Windows 10 show the password textbox at startup, rather than that picture with the time & date?

Tags: windows-10

As soon as Windows 10 boots, it shows a picture together with the clock and date. The user has to click / press a button before the password can be written. This is an extra step that I do not wish to have in the way. I'd like the password prompt to be displayed immediately after boot. How can I do this?

Comment: Disable the lock screen....how you do that on the current version of Windows 10 has been explained in another answer to a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Anniversary Update Builds**

There is a workaround to disable the Lock Screen in Anniversary Update builds, in any edition of Windows.

Create a Scheduled Task that runs the following command-line, or a batch/script that runs the following command:

```
reg.exe add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData /t REG_DWORD /v AllowLockScreen /d 0 /f
```

The idea is to reset the `AllowLockScreen` value data to 0 on these two trigger events:

- Log on
- Workstation unlock.

So you need to use multiple triggers for that task.

(or)

Download the Task XML from here:
[How to Disable the Lock Screen in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607)?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-lock-screen-anniversary-update-windows-10/)

And use the Import Task option in Scheduler to create/import the task automatically.

Lock the workstation and unlock it. From the 2nd time onwards you shouldn't see the lock screen.

**For Pre-Anniversary Update Builds**

This can be done by editing the registry (or using the Local Group Policy editor in Windows 10 Pro and higher versions prior to the "Anniversary Update" release).

(Assumes your system is not part of a domain.)

Start `Regedit.exe` and go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
```

Create a subkey named `Personalization`

Select `Personalization` and in the right-pane, create a REG_DWORD value named `NoLockScreen` and set its value data to `1`.

Exit the Registry Editor.

This registry edit corresponds to the following GPO.

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel >
>   Personalization > Do not display the lock screen

Comment: This group policy is ignored on version 1607.  The registry key still works though

Comment: The registry key does not work for me - in fact, this key was already present prior to performing the Anniversary Update and was retained during that update, but it no longer seems to remove to pre-lock screen background display. (Trying to figure out what the screen is actually called is frustratingly elusive, too!)

Comment: This GPO (and the registry entry it sets) stopped having an effect on Home/Pro with the release of the Anniversary Update. It's now an Enterprise/Edu/Server GPO only. See http://betanews.com/2016/07/28/windows-10-anniversary-update-takes-back-control/, and/or http://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/28/microsoft-removes-policies-windows-10-pro/, etc.

Comment: I cannot import the XML-File anymore. Parsing it failed on 2004

Answer (score 0):

For Pro editions of windows (tested on Win10 and Win11):

1. Go to `Group Policy editor`
2. Go to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization`
3. Open `Do not display the lock screen` (ENABLE it!)