# How do I get rid of the background window ahead of the Windows 10 lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I don't want to get the of the lock screen.  If I hit Windows+L I want it to go directly to the lock screen.  Instead, it goes to a background screen that I have to click or otherwise interact with to get to the lock screen - I can't just start typing my password!  The same thing happens if I power up my computer out of sleep.

I have looked under `Settings -> Lock Screen` and I can see where I can change the picture for this background, but not how to skip this screen entirely.

I don't know what this extra background screen is called, but I want to get rid of it!  How do I do this?  I used to have it configured this way, but when I applied the Windows Anniversary Update yesterday it reverted to putting this annoying extra screen in the way.

Comment: The `NoLockScreen` registry edit should help. See y'days post on this topic [How can I make Windows 10 show the password textbox at startup, rather than that picture with the time & date? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/1107975/how-can-i-make-windows-10-show-the-password-textbox-at-startup-rather-than-that/1107980#1107980)

Comment: Possible duplicate??

Comment: @w32sh I tried the registry answer you provided in that question, only to discover that key already exists and has a value of 1!

Comment: Interesting! The registry based policy (as well as the GPO setting) not working here after installing Anniversary update. I can confirm that.

Comment: @w32sh That GPO stopped working in Home/Pro with the Anniversary update;, it's now an Enterprise/Edu GPO only.

Comment: @ Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yep. Heard that. but thought the registry edit would work..but didn't.

Comment: @w32sh with 1607 the entry has no effect on Home/Pro only Enterprise/Education

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround to disable the Lock Screen in **Anniversary Update** builds, in any edition of Windows.

Create a Scheduled Task that runs the following command-line, or a batch/script that runs the following command:

```
reg.exe add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData /t REG_DWORD /v AllowLockScreen /d 0 /f
```

The idea is to reset the `AllowLockScreen` value data to 0 on these two trigger events:

- Log on
- Workstation unlock.

So you need to use multiple triggers for that task.

(or)

Download the Task XML from here:
[How to Disable the Lock Screen in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607)?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-lock-screen-anniversary-update-windows-10/)

And use the Import Task option in Scheduler to create/import the task automatically.

Lock the workstation and unlock it. From the 2nd time onwards you shouldn't see the lock screen.

Comment: this only works partially. When you boot the system the lockscreen is still there, but when you lock the device (WIN+L) it works and I'm directly at the screen to enter my password/pin

Comment: Yes. Looks like there is no way to disable the initial lock screen (at startup). At startup, the system doesn't seem to use `LockApp.exe`. May be it uses a core module.

Comment: may it helps to use registry to edit Image File Execution Options for LockScreen.exe and point to a dummy exe?

Comment: Debugger is ignored at startup. Both for lockapp.exe and lockapphost.exe. But debugger for lockapp.exe correctly runs when locking the workstation. FYI, I tried with a dummy executable like `rundll32.exe` as well as with a non-existent exe. Setting debugger for `lockapphost.exe` causes a hang when locking.

Comment: Thank you!!!   Also to note, from the linked article, you can also renamed the LockApp folder, which doesn't even require setting up a scheduled task.

Comment: It's not working for me, I don't have any password set but I am force to click on the Log in button, so dumb. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the Version 1607, [you can't disable the LockScreen on Pro Editions, only on Education and Enterprise.](http://winaero.com/blog/microsoft-locks-some-group-policy-options-to-enterprise-editions-in-windows-10-anniversary-update/)

[image]

So setting the Registry key or GPO has no effect. Update to Enterprise if you are a business user or submit Feedback to bringt it back to Pro.

Comment: So... Microsoft basically removed this capability for me?  Meaning now I have to go through an extra inconvenience every time I step away from my machine and come back?  Are they trying to make my computer less secure by discouraging me from bringing up the lock screen?  What is the reasoning behind removing a feature I was relying on to work more efficiently?

Comment: ask Microsoft why they did this nonsense. Use the feedback hub and provide feedback to MS.