# How to completely bypass Windows 10 login prompt after sleep without password set?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, login, login-screen, wake-up

When you put your Windows 10 machine to sleep, and then hit a key to bring it back up in a while, it shows you the picture, when you get rid of that, it asks you to hit the login button - even when you don't actually have a password set - before taking you to desktop (with start menu open... -.-). This is a grand total of minimum of 3 key presses (wake, lose login screen, login, not counting the escape key for getting rid of start menu) before seeing my desktop.

The behaviour I want to end up with is that it takes just one keypress (wake) before I see my desktop exactly the way I left it from sleep, like I'm able to on previous versions of Windows (with some conf) and OSX. Is there any way to accomplish that or is my only option finding OCD meds for what is otherwise a rather simple UX flaw (when you don't have a password set, sleep should return you to desktop)?

Edition: Professional
Version: 1607 (Build 14393.187)

Comment: If this is possible entirely depends on the version of Windows you are running?  So are you running `Windows 10 Home` or `Windows 10 Professional`?  Are you running version 1607 or 1511?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that that this actually matters with Windows! It's Professional, version 1607

Comment: The lockscreen cannot be disabled in the version of Windows your using.  The logon screen behavior can be changed, by setting the relevant group policy, the [lockscreen can only be disabled in Enterprise/Education](http://superuser.com/questions/1108435/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-background-window-ahead-of-the-windows-10-lock-screen/1109609#1109609) versions of Windows 10 at this time.  There is a workaround that you might acceptable.  I just disabled the screensaver/sleep mode and setup Windows to automatically log into my account so I never see the lockscreen personally.

Comment: You should install KB3194496, in order to bring your installation up to the current build, at your earliest convience.

Comment: I have that installed. Now what?

Comment: Installing KB3194496 was just a friendly suggestion.  I linked to the workaround for the lockscreen and a suggestion on how to configure the machine so it doesn't require you to log into it after it comes out of a screensaver/sleep