# How do I disable password on windows 10 home edition after wake up from sleep? (netplwiz already tested)

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

I have windows home 10 Microsoft Surface Go with version 1803 (OS build 17134.345) that I gave a local user and password.

I have used netplwiz to disable password login and this seems to work when restarting the device.

Unfortunately, when the device wakes up from sleep, it still asks for a password.

I have checked if by accident a screen saver is running that may cause a reauthentication but it's not running.

I can't find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [The lock screen cannot be disabled in Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/1131016/how-to-completely-bypass-windows-10-login-prompt-after-sleep-without-password-se?rq=1), the group policy that would disable it, is not applicable to either version.  However, if the account were to have no password, you could basically automatically log into the account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of the background window ahead of the Windows 10 lock screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108435/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-background-window-ahead-of-the-windows-10-lock-screen).  By the way, the answer that refers to 1607, is applicable to the current version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options*, under *Require sign-in*,
select *Never* from the drop-down box.

[image]

Comment: In my case it was on 15 minutes and just changed it to never.... If this works I'll be back to accept your answer.... already many thanks for your reply

Comment: I don't seem to have this problem anymore... your solution worked !

Comment: I don't have this option in that menu. I am on 1803

Comment: @HermanToothrot: Instead of downvoting, you could show a screenshot of what you have, since what you claim seems impossible.

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood the question, you are right.

Answer (score -2):

In the sign in menu there should be a settings, you can select it to not asking password after wake up :)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. To make your answer more usable, please explain how to do this. If possible add a screen shot. How is the setting called?