# How to disable auto login in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

My wife doesn't use a password on her account so when I boot into Windows 11, I always have to log out of her account first because it logs her in automatically. How can I disable that without giving her a password?

Comment: The behavior you describe has nothing to do with the account NOT having a password. 
 You just need enable `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.` after running netplwiz

Comment: This might also be a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1378768/how-do-i-disable-password-on-windows-10-home-edition-after-wake-up-from-sleep) question.  I know netplwiz  still exists on Windows 11, I just don't know if, `Sign-in Options` was significant;y changed.  I highly doubt it though.

Comment: @Ramhound: netplwiz still exists on Windows 11 but I don't see any option to disable auto login.

Comment: Do you see the `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.` checkbox?  You should enable it.  Your system has a user, defined as the default user, when your system boots the user is automatically logged in.  By indicating the user must supply a password, that user will have to enter a password, in the case of a user without a password it's a blank password.

Comment: Same issue is annoying me. None of the solutions here do what I'm after. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @MilesHayler: Unfortunately not.

Comment: This "solution" does not work at all, option is being ignored.

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue in Windows 11. As Ramhound wrote in a comment, you just need enable **Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer** after running netplwiz. However, this checkbox can be missing  ([as mentioned here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/users-must-enter-a-user-name-and-password-to-use-this-computer-missing-windows-10/)).

To get the checkbox back, set DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion to 0 in registry branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device

Comment: The checkbox was indeed missing and did reappear after setting the value to 0 but checking it did unfortunately not stop autologin.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-login can be set in the registry. If that's your case, you may remove
it like this:

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
- Right-click the following items and select "Delete":
  `AutoAdminLogon`, `DefaultUserName`, `DefaultPassword`
- Logout/login or reboot to test.

Comment: I don't have those keys, and yet this still happens. I do have "AutoLogonSID", which is suspicious

Answer (score 0):

1. **Open Netplwiz**:

   - Press `Windows Key + R` to open the Run dialog.
   - Type `netplwiz` and press `Enter`.
2. **User Accounts**:

   - In the "User Accounts" window, you'll see a list of all user accounts on your PC.
   - Click on the user account for which you want to disable auto-login.
3. **Uncheck the Option**:

   - At the top of the window, you'll see an option labeled "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer." Make sure this box is checked.
4. **Apply and Close**:

   - Click `Apply` and then `OK`.
5. **Restart your Computer*

Answer (score -1):

Disable auto login for Windows10 and 11 with this simple steps.

1. go to settings> Accounts.
2. On the left side of the window you will
   find Sign In Options.
3. Click on Sign in options and you will find
   "If you’ve been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again" Toggle When PC wakes up from sleep.
   You can try [other alternatives](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-login-sleep-windows-7-8) if you are using a older version of Windows.